# Как узнать позицию скролла внизу?

Tags: javascript

если надо к примеру сделать кнопку навверх, то идет scrollTop: 0, ибо 0 - начала документа. А если сделать наооборот. Вкраце как узнать значения скролла в конец страницы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуй. btnScrollDown твоя кнопка, узнать высоту можно с помощью document.documentElement.clientHeight. Замени в querySelector('#scroll_down') на свой и скрипт будет работать. Подробнее можешь почитать  [Размеры и прокрутка страницы](https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window)

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var btnScrollDown = document.querySelector('#scroll_down');

  function scrollDown() {
    var windowCoords = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    (function scroll() {
      if (window.pageYOffset < windowCoords) {
        window.scrollBy(0, 10);
        setTimeout(scroll, 0);
      }
      if (window.pageYOffset > windowCoords) {
        window.scrollTo(0, windowCoords);
      }
    })();
  }

  btnScrollDown.addEventListener('click', scrollDown);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

clientHeight для определения высот, значит:

```
document.body.clientHeight
```